# Window size is larger than screen size?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, screen

When I check the screen.width using javascript in my Chrome browser, it reports 1920, which is what I expect.  If I drag my Chrome window out to the full width of my screen and check $(window).width(), I get 2133???  Does the browser use it's own units?

I'm working on some HTML/CSS layouts and trying to make them consistent across different screen resolutions and browser window sizes, but I'm having some issues, so I want to try to understand this issue better.

By request here is the code (in the javascript console):

```
screen.width()
$(window).width()
```

For window.devicePixelRatio, I get: 0.8999999761581421

Comment: Can you provide your code for checking?

Comment: What output do you get for `window.devicePixelRatio`?

Comment: Is it possible that when you move the window is gets its normal width (as if resized manually, bigger than the screen max - 2133), and when to full screen it stretches to the maximum default (1920)?

Comment: There you have it: `2133 *  0.89999  = 1920`.

Comment: I guess I can look this up -- but can anybody tell me briefly what window.devicePixelRatio is?  I mean, it's clearly the ratio between the window pixels and the screen pixels, but what is the reasoning behind having the two different units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct behaviour.  The window object represents an open window in a browser, not your screen/monitor. Here is more information about the window object in a Document Object Modal (DOM):  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

In particular, this issue is concerns the window.devicePixelRatio, as pointed out by @gus27:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @NikhilDevre I'd like to mention, that on desktop browsers the `devicePixelRatio` can be influenced by the zoom factor you set in your browser:

Using Chrome and setting a zoom factor of 90% you'll get a `devicePixelRatio` of 0.8999.

Comment: Interesting.  My page zoom is set to 100%.  But as previously stated, my devicePixelRatio is 0.8999

Comment: @MichaelMcCrickard If you use a Mac maybe [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33444/how-do-you-reset-screen-zoom-to-zero) can help.

Comment: That does help!  I didn't realize those zoom controls were under Accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at *viewport* meta header, useful if you want responsive behavior on mobile.

Having something like this can make your website properly scale if you have @media tags in you CSS.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

More details in [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag).